# Context for RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-context

I want to add `ProgressDialog` in an adapter. AFAIK, `.this` for activity, and `getActivity.getApplicationContext()` for fragment. What about adapter? Is it possible?

I got error `Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?` when I use `mContext.getApplicationContext()`.

EDIT:

In a fragment, I show cards by

```
allGroupsView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.allGroupsView);
adapterGroup = new AdapterGroup(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), results);
allGroupsView.setAdapter(adapterGroup);
allGroupsView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
```

In class `AdapterGroup`

```
public class AdapterGroup extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<DataGroup> data= Collections.emptyList();
DataGroup current;

public AdapterGroup(Context context, List<DataGroup> results) {
    this.mContext = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    this.data = results;
}

// Inflate the layout when viewholder created
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view_row, parent, false);
    final MyHolder holder = new MyHolder(view);

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("debug", String.valueOf(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
            getDetails(Config.GET_GROUP_DETAILS_URL, data.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).groupName, data.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).description);
        }
    });

    return holder;
}

private void getDetails(String url, String groupName, String description) {

    groupName = groupName.replace(" ", "%20");
    description = description.replace(" ", "%20");

    final String finalGroupName = groupName;
    final String finalDescription = description;

    class GetDetails extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(mContext.getApplicationContext(), null, "Please wait", true, true);
            loading.setCancelable(false);
        } // more code down from here
```

Comment: create `constructor` of your adapter and pass context from `activity/fragment`

Comment: `Activity` already is a `Context`. Why do you need `getApplicationContext`? Same question for `mContext.getApplicationContext()`...

Comment: @cricket_007 the class is not an `Activity`, so I figured probably I can use the same way with fragment. The exception proved I can't :/

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] of all classes involved? `getActivity()` is what you use in a Fragment

Comment: @cricket_007 I have added more codes

Answer (score 9):

I've seen a lot of code where people keep reference to the Context in an Adapter.  But in a RecyclerView.Adapter, the **itemView** (the view you already inflated from **onCreateViewHolder**) is accessible from your ViewHolder.  For the most part, you should be dealing with the viewHolder anyways.  So, use viewholder.itemView.getContext();.  You can even expose a method in your viewholder getContext().

```
public Context getContext() {return itemView.getContext();}
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, there are some differences between type of **Contexts**.
Reference: https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/

Example:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
     return new ViewHolder(v);
} 

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    Context context = viewHolder.anyView.getContext();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom `Adapter` and add a `Constructor` so that the `Context` can be passed.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> stringList = null;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.stringList = objects;
    }
}
```

Use this 'context' variable to show the `ProgressDialog` as per your requirement.

Comment: Question asked about RecyclerView.Adapter. Besides, storing the `context` member variable in a `ArrayAdapter` is redundant.

Comment: You can use this for a RecyclerView Adapter as well.

Comment: Sure. I think the question already is doing this, though, as `mContext` appears to be the variable in the adapter and `mContext.getApplicationContext` is throwing an exception

Comment: Did not have the code previously and the edit had been done after this answer. So using only mContext, a ProgressDialog could be started.

Comment: if I use `mContext` only without `getApplicationContext` it also throw the same exception

Comment: @August That may be because you also assigned `mContext` with a call to `getApplicationContext` when you initialized the adapter.

Comment: You initialize Adapter variable inside a Fragment?

Answer (score 1):

1.Pass activity context in constructor for adapter. if your calling from fragment pass it as getActivity().

2.You can also try itemView.getContext() in onBindViewHolder.

I am not sure about pros and cons of using #2 method because I always use #1.

Comment: can you please take a look at my newly added codes?

Comment: By seeing updated code I feel its better to pass context in constructor.

Answer (score 1):

In fragment add:

```
Context context;
#in onCreateView method:
context=getActivity();
allGroupsView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.allGroupsView);
adapterGroup = new AdapterGroup(context,results);
allGroupsView.setAdapter(adapterGroup);
allGroupsView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

dont use getActivity.getApplicationContext() or context.getApplicationContext()

```
loading = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, null, "Please wait", true, true);
```

Comment: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for me try it In Place of Grid You Use LinearLayoutManager

```
Context mContext;

this.mContext = getActivity();


public void setAdapter() {
    adapter = new AllCategoriesAdapter(mContext, allCategoriesList);
    gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    ItemOffsetDecoration itemDecoration = new ItemOffsetDecoration(getActivity(), R.dimen.item_margin);
    gridRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
    gridRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    gridRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    gridRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    gridRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

   }



public class AllCategoriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {


Context mContext;
List<AllCategories> allCategoriesList = new ArrayList<AllCategories>();

public AllCategoriesAdapter(Context mContext, List<AllCategories> allCategoriesList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.allCategoriesList = allCategoriesList;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.allcategories_item, null);
    AllCategoriesHolder holder = new AllCategoriesHolder(itemView);
    holder.imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    holder.imageView_heart = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_heart);
    holder.textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    holder.textViewPlace = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPlace);
    holder.textViewPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPrice);
    itemView.setTag(holder);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getDetails();
        }
    });

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    AllCategoriesHolder vh = (AllCategoriesHolder) holder;

    AllCategories allCategories = allCategoriesList.get(position);
    vh.textViewName.setText("" + allCategoriesList.get(position).getName());
    vh.textViewPlace.setText("" + allCategoriesList.get(position).getPlace());
    vh.textViewPrice.setText("" + allCategoriesList.get(position).getPrice());

    if (allCategories.isHeartLike()) {

    } else {

    }

    try {
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(allCategories.getImageUrl())
                .placeholder(PlaceHolderDrawableHelper.getBackgroundDrawable(position))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .crossFade()
                .into(vh.imageView);
    } catch (NullPointerException ne) {
        ne.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ia) {
        ia.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return allCategoriesList.size();
}

public void getDetails() {

    new GetDetails().execute();

}

class GetDetails extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog loading;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        loading = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "", "Please wait", true, true);
        loading.setCancelable(false);
    } // more code

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return null;
    }


}

}
```